# Cannot run Angular-cli at node 10.16.0

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular8

Here is my computer information:

1. node version 10.16.0
2. npm version 6.9.0
3. Environment Variables `C:\Users\tran.sonhoang\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`

My problem is when I run `ng new app-name` I will get the file with this info

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

// Provide a title to the process in `ps`.
// Due to an obscure Mac bug, do not start this title with any symbol.
try {
  process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');
} catch(_) {
  // If an error happened above, use the most basic title.
  process.title = 'ng';
}

// Some older versions of Node do not support let or const.
var version = process.version.substr(1).split('.');
if (Number(version[0]) < 10 || (Number(version[0]) === 10 && Number(version[1]) < 9)) {
  process.stderr.write(
    'You are running version ' + process.version + ' of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.\n' +
    'The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.\n\n' +
    'Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.\n'
  );

  process.exit(3);
}

require('../lib/init');
```

This issue is so strange to me since this is the first time I see this issue with angular-cli.

What I have tried:

1. Removed node and install again the same version.
2. Remove npm cache + update npm
3. Remove Angular-cli and re-install

But It still not fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Run ng --version in your commandline to get your CLI version. I think your ng ( CLI ) version is 8 which is required nodejs 12.

Comment: I cant run `ng`. Every time I run `ng` then I get this file. I think min requirement node for Angular 8 is 10.9.0.

Comment: what Os do you use windows or ubantu ?

Comment: Run npm i @angular/cli -g again or unistall/install it

Comment: Angular 8 requires nodejs version 12 , so you will have to upgrade nodejs to latest or you could use  nvm and installl   node version 12 using the commnad `nvm install 12` and then `nvm use 12` then try running the `ng new sample_app`

Comment: Window 10 @JoelJoseph. something wrong but I am working with Angular from Angular 2 rc1. But this is the first time I see this.

Comment: okay @JoelJoseph. I will update it to node 12. But why on [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) is 10.9.0

Comment: @HoangTranSon nodejs 10 is LTS verson  , 12 is the latest. I think the Angular team forgot to update the doc after release

Comment: I updated to node 12.4.0 but the error still happen. @JoelJoseph. I will try to find the root cause. since from the error it is just version 10.9.0 is okay. So I dont think nodejs version is a problem here.

Comment: @JoelJoseph you re right 50%. I have to change my environment variables too `C:\Users\tran.sonhoang\AppData\Roaming\npm` where have `ng.cmd` since I am using Window I think.